# Getting 'Interpolate Error' in Denoto, on Delimited File Base View, using date variables

Tags: denodo

Denodo Data source is a Delimited file with variables in the local path for the date range. A Base View is created using interpolation variables. Querying the data with a start and end date filled in results in this error:

> Interpolate Error: 'Unparseable date: "672"': Unparseable date: "672"'

or

> Interpolate Error: 'Unparseable date: "2016"': Unparseable date:
>   "2016"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When entering a date in the quick query section, make sure to use single quotes around the variable data.

Example: start_date = `'2016/01/01'` not `2016/01/01`